hotkey to move a tab from one window to another in a browser
I have 2 browser windows opened. I can drag a tab from one window to another with my mouse. Also, in chromium-based browsers there's a special button in context menu, when clicking on a tab. But is there a way to do this with keyboard only?
The most I have found so far is that in browser Vivaldi you can set up a hotkey for moving the tab to a new window, not the existing one.
